# CodeIgniter Undefined property when loading a model

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm receiving the following errors whilst trying to implement a very simple model controller in codeigniter. I'm new to the framework but as far as I can see this should work.

I've also tried auto loading the model. I am autoloading the database library.

```
Message: Undefined property: User::$user_model

Fatal error: Call to a member function get_user() on a non-object
```

The model

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
{

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}


function get_user()
{
    return "test";
}


}
```

The controller

```
class User extends CI_Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->model('User_model');

    $data['value'] = $this->User_model->get_user();

    $this->load->view('user_edit', $data);
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Weird, that should theoretically work.What's the file name of the model, is it `user_model.php` ?

Comment: Yes it's user_model.php, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i've found the problem. I had some additional setter methods in my user controller which i've used all the time, didnt think they would be a problem.

```
    public function __set($key, $value)
{
    // Check to see that the requested attribute exists and then assign the value
    if (property_exists($this, $key))
    {
        $this->$key = $value;
    } 
}
```

turns out I needed to take away one of the underscores as codeigniter doesn't like it.

```
public function _set($key, $value)
```

I should have really included the full class but I was trying to keep it as simple as possible!

Answer (score 2):

just use some thing like this, `$this->load->model('user_model');` don't use `$this->load->model('User_model');` and make sure you have same name, when the model name like `user_mode.php` and the class like `class User_model extends CI_Model(){}` so when you call it from controller use the lower case look like your model name user `$this->load->model('user_model')`